# Wordpress get user id by login name

Tags: wordpress

How do i get the user id from user login name in wordpress?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By using [`get_userdatabylogin`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdatabylogin):

```
$user = get_userdatabylogin('loginname');
if($user){
   echo $user->ID;
}
```

Example:

```
$user = get_userdatabylogin('admin');
if($user) echo $user->ID; // Outputs 1
```

---

**UPDATE**: the function `get_userdatabylogin` has been deprecated, and replaced with `get_user_by()`. Refer to Dalen's [solution to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9024155/835950).

Comment: Please bold the word **Update:** so its easier to spot the deprecation note.

Answer (score 41):

`get_userdatabylogin` is now deprecated, it is possible to get the same result via

[**`get_user_by`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by)

example :

```
$user = get_user_by('login','loginname');
if($user)
{
   echo $user->ID;
}
```

[**link**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18333) to the ticket about this change

Answer (score 2):

You also can use [get_current_user_id()](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_current_user_id)

```
<?php
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    echo "ID User : ".$user_id ;
    if ($user_id == 0) {
        echo 'You are currently not logged in.';
    } else {
        echo 'You are logged in as user '.$user_id;
    }
?>
```